# Jquery Mobile all links ignore data-role="none"

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working with jquery mobile and I've found that even when I add `data-role="none"` to an anchor tag, it is still getting intercepted by the mobile ui and treated as ajax. I have one link which I need to pull the ui out of the flow and this is causing it to fail.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup? What is the anchor supposed to do, and what is it currently doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

> **Linking without Ajax**
>
> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false")
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external"
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior

So you have to use either `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` instead of `data-role="none"`.