# Clicking on a rails link_to link does not generate response from Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This one has got me stumped, I have a:

```
<%= link_to 'Login', users_path %>
```

That generates the html:

```
<a href="/users" class="ui-link">Login</a>
```

And when I click on it, I don't get a response back from the Server.  The address bar shows the correct url, `http://localhost:3000/users`, but nothing happens.  When I click the address bar and hit enter, I get a response and I am directed to the users page.

In my routes.rb, the users entry is simply: `resources :users`

It also looks like it puts `localhost:3000/#/users` into the address bar and Chrome removes the #, could that be the cause and why is it putting the hash in there?

I ran Fiddler to see if the http request was being sent and sure enough, both sent to the server.

Can anyone explain this phenomenon?  All my links are behaving this way, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's in your `development.log`?  Make sure it's hitting the controller and look for errors there.  Are you using an authentication plugin, like Devise or something?

Comment: @JimStewart, not using an authentication plugin, good idea on the dev logs, I noticed that a normal entry was logged to the Users controller on the failed request, but nothing to indicate a failure.

Comment: @Swards, Interesting, the initial testing was done in Chrome, but when I tried in IE, it failed the same, but put an address of http://localhost:3000/#/users into the address bar which also did not work...

Comment: Using a javascript framework?

Comment: @Swards, nope, I have JQuery Mobile library, but it's not even being referenced in the Application or User call

Comment: 'ui-link' being referenced anywhere else?  Could a js function be turning that into a remote call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:  [Jquery Mobile all links ignore data-role="none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283490/jquery-mobile-all-links-ignore-data-role-none)

You have to use either `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"`.

Comment: you are the man!  Adding the rel did the trick, I had a 'require tree .' in my application.js, doh!  That was a tricky one to find, I am very thankful!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using devise or some other user-management-tool? Then there might be no root to /users.

You can run the following command to see, which routes are available:

```
rake routes
```

If you are using devise, try the following URL to find out, if it works:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

Comment: I'm not using Devise, in fact, if I click on what the link puts in my address bar, http://localhost:3000/users, it navigates correctly to the users view

Comment: Have you tried `rake routes` to see where `users_path` directs to?

Comment: Looks normal 'users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index'

Comment: Looks like it is putting a hash in the address and Chrome corrects it, so it initially tries ' localhost:3000/#/users' and then Chrome removes the #, could that be the cause?

Comment: Have you tried another browser like firefox, if the problem occurs there?

Comment: Same result in all browsers